# when deployed on heroku then user login is not working otherwise it was working properly and it is showing error auth user doesnot exists

Tags: django, python-2.7, heroku

hey I am first time deploying my django app to heroku so I am getting this error when i started app on heroku and tried to log in but I am getting error as auth user is not defined... But when I tried to run the same app on my local server before deployment it was working fine. Please help me with this.

check that link also:- http://aqueous-ridge-4845.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your error:

```
relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user..
```

suggests that the database hasn't been migrated which sounds like you need to run

`heroku run python manage.py syncdb`

to setup the Db